# ng-click will not work after two clicks firefox only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I have been researching this question and cannot find a good reason why this doesn't work. I am trying to set up a select all checkbox in the table header of a div. My current solution works in all browsers except Firefox. It will work when clicked for the firs  time and will work when clicked again, but will not work again.  My console will show the value two times then it is not registering.
Here is my code:
HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive" ng-controller="ReportsController">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="myreport table table-striped sortable"  style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<thead>
<tr >
<th class="myreport_header" ><p class="titleheader">
<input type="checkbox"  ng-click="toggleAll()" ng-model="isAllSelected" > Select</p>
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>    
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isAllSelected" ></td>
<td>sample</td>                        
<td>New</td>
</tr>
<tr>    
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-checked="isAllSelected" ></td>
<td>sample2</td>                        
<td>old</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
reportsApp.controller('ReportsController', function ($scope, $http,$filter, $q, $window) {
$scope.isAllSelected = false;
console.log($scope.isAllSelected)

$scope.toggleAll = function() {
    if ($scope.isAllSelected) {
        $scope.isAllSelected = true;
    } else {
        $scope.isAllSelected = false;
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some weird $event related issues in firefox.  To exclude them can you change the checkbox to a button and see if you are still able to replicate the issue.  My guess is the event just stops firing after being set for a checkbox but won't for a button.